# Is there an imapable for latest devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, imap

We have a few internal Rails apps which are planned to let users login in via imap credentials. Is there a updated [Imapable](https://github.com/joshk/devise_imapable) for the latest (v3.2.2) [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) ?

Answer (score 1):

According to https://github.com/joshk/devise_imapable/network, try one of [1](https://github.com/alzuin/devise_imapable), [2](https://github.com/YouthTree/devise_imapable), [3](https://github.com/yonpols/devise_imapable), or [4](https://github.com/LouisStAmour/devise_imapable).